# Jenkins cannot execute Maven command: "An error has occurred while checking scm status. Unable to discover client"

Tags: maven, jenkins, perforce

I'm currently getting a new Jenkins server running, going from version 2.128 to 2.222. I have several projects that are all failing with the same error due to a problem communicating with my SCM through Maven. Here is the error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ drizzlesizzle ---

[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/drizzlesizzle-laurenc/target
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/drizzlesizzle-laurenc/target/classes
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/drizzlesizzle-laurenc/target/test-classes
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/drizzlesizzle-laurenc/target/site
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-jackson-versions) @ drizzlesizzle ---
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireSameVersions
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) @ drizzlesizzle ---

[DEBUG] Verifying there are no local modifications ...
[DEBUG] info
[DEBUG] Command completed in 37ms
[DEBUG] clients -m2147483647 -up4-daemon
[DEBUG] Command completed in 38ms
[DEBUG] Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
[ERROR] Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.578 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-08T22:05:54+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/188M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project drizzlesizzle: An error has occurred while checking scm status. Unable to discover client: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project drizzlesizzle: An error has occurred while checking scm status.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error has occurred while checking scm status.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.checkForLocalModifications(CreateMojo.java:479)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute(CreateMojo.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Unable to discover client
    at com.perforce.maven.scm.provider.p4.manager.DefaultP4ClientManager.getClient(DefaultP4ClientManager.java:151)
    at com.perforce.maven.scm.provider.p4.manager.DefaultP4ClientManager.getClient(DefaultP4ClientManager.java:75)
    at com.perforce.maven.scm.provider.p4.P4ScmProvider.login(P4ScmProvider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.login(AbstractScmProvider.java:747)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.status(AbstractScmProvider.java:789)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getStatus(CreateMojo.java:544)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.checkForLocalModifications(CreateMojo.java:475)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Unable to discover client
    at com.perforce.maven.scm.provider.p4.manager.DefaultP4ClientManager.discoverClientName(DefaultP4ClientManager.java:402)
    at com.perforce.maven.scm.provider.p4.manager.DefaultP4ClientManager.getClient(DefaultP4ClientManager.java:90)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.perforce.p4java.exception.RequestException: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

    at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.getClients(Server.java:1003)
    at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.getClients(Server.java:969)
    at com.perforce.maven.scm.provider.p4.manager.DefaultP4ClientManager.discoverClientName(DefaultP4ClientManager.java:364)
    ... 41 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This happens when I have the Build/Goals and options settings of Jenkins to "-X --update-snapshots clean verify".
I have noticed that all of the projects that fail with this have the same scm tag in their pom.xml. Here is one of those poms:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.sustaining</groupId>
    <artifactId>sustaining-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>drizzlesizzle</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>drizzlesizzle</name>

  <properties>
    <mock-server.version>3.10.4</mock-server.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-uber-jar</id>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>com.sustaining.drizzlesizzle.server.DrizzlesizzleStarter</Main-Class>
                    <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-jackson-versions</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireSameVersions>
                  <dependencies>
                    <dependency>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations</dependency>
                    <dependency>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310</dependency>
                  </dependencies>
                </requireSameVersions>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- project specific -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sustaining.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>CommandExecutor</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sustaining.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>CoReClient</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sustaining.util</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sustaining.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>jar-extractor</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sustaining.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>unzipper</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sustaining.can</groupId>
      <artifactId>cancommand2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sustaining.can</groupId>
      <artifactId>CanClient2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON with Jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Swagger API docs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-bundle</artifactId>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.meanbean</groupId>
      <artifactId>meanbean</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
      <version>${mock-server.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <description>A Java service that exposes a RESTful interface to talk to tape drives, usually with ITDT.</description>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:p4:perforce.domain.com:1666://Sustaining/drizzletizzle-standard-test/drizzlesizzle</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:p4:perforce.domain.com:1666://Sustaining/drizzletizzle-standard-test/drizzlesizzle</developerConnection>
    <url>http://perforce.domain.com:8080/@md=d&amp;cd=//Sustaining/hptizzle/&amp;c=ZSb@//Sustaining/drizzletizzle/drizzlesizzle/?ac=83</url>
  </scm>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>JIRA</system>
    <url>https://jira.domain.com/projects/SUSDT/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>
  <ciManagement>
    <system>Jenkins</system>
    <url>http://works:8888/job/drizzlesizzle/</url>
  </ciManagement>

  <!-- Jenkins build plugins, for static code analysis -->
  <profiles>
    <!-- Jenkins by default defines a property BUILD_NUMBER which is used to enable the profile. -->
    <profile>
      <id>jenkins</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env.BUILD_NUMBER</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <!-- JaCoCo coverage -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Run Checkstyle -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Run FindBugs -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Run PMD and the copy paste detector -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Attach Javadocs -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>

        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I have 8 projects that are failing for this error, which all have the same SCM syntax:

```
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:p4:perforce.domain.com:1666://Sustaining/drizzletizzle-standard-test/drizzlesizzle</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:p4:perforce.domain.com:1666://Sustaining/drizzletizzle-standard-test/drizzlesizzle</developerConnection>
    <url>http://perforce.domain.com:8080/@md=d&amp;cd=//Sustaining/hptizzle/&amp;c=ZSb@//Sustaining/drizzletizzle/drizzlesizzle/?ac=83</url>
  </scm>
```

I have a few projects that are on SVN that are not having this problem. I also have a couple dozen projects that do not use the maven scm plugin option at all, and they can connect to my Perforce server just fine.
I have tried changing the formatting of the connections (changing p4 to perforce, which then failed for a missing password), removing the scm entirely, and adding the buildnumber-maven-plugin to the pom.

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>com.perforce.p4maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>p4maven-provider</artifactId>
                <version>${p4maven.version}</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: The error message says "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset." This means you need to "p4 login" that username.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I did not have the Maven Info plugin install in Jenkins. Once installed, all of my projects built without issue.